# Populating select options from database on tabulator?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tabulator

can you help me Populating select options from the database I'm using Tabulator to update data from the database dynamically can you check the code below and tell me how I can save data on the database or there any other way I can use Populating

Full Code on a tabulator JS

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var tabledata = {!! $Payment !!};
  var Paymentcat = {!! $Paymentcat !!};
  var contract = {!! $Contract !!};  
  var paymentmethod = {!! $PaymentMethod !!};  
  var product = {!! $Product !!};  

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table-theme", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columnCalcs:"both",
    paginationSize:20,
    pagination: "local", // Enable local pagination
    paginationSizeSelector:[10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200],
    paginationCounter:"rows",
    data: tabledata,
    columns: [
      { title: "Payment ID", field: "PaymentID", editor: "input"},
      { title: "Payment Category",field: "category.Name", editor: "list",
                editorParams: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
                var options = {};
                Paymentcat.forEach(function(item) {
                options[item.ID] = item.Name;
                });
                // Return the options for the editor
                return {
                 values: options ,
             };
         },    
      },
      {
        title: "Select Contract /Product",
        field: "Descriptions",
        editor: "list",
        editorParams: function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
          var rowData = cell.getRow().getData();
          var category = rowData.category.Name;
          var netpay = rowData.NetPay;
          var options = {};
        
          if (category === "Product Payment" || category === "1") {
            product.forEach(function(item) {
              options[item.Name] = item.Name;
          });
  
          } else if (category === "Membership Payment" || category === "2" ) {
            contract.forEach(function(item) {
              options[item.Package] = item.Package;
          });
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          } else if (category === "3") {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           
          } else if (category === "4") {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          }
          return {
            values: options,
          };
        }
      },
      { title: "Net Pay (₱)", field: "NetPay", editor: "number" },
      { title: "Discount", field: "Discount", editor: "number" },
      { title: "Grand Total", field: "GrandTotal", editor: "number", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcParams:{
       precision:2,}},
      { title: "Date Sale", field: "DateSale", editor: "date"},
      { title: "Payment Method",field: "PaymentMethod", editor: "list",
                editorParams: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
                var options = {};
                paymentmethod.forEach(function(item) {
                options[item.Name] = item.Name;
                });
                // Return the options for the editor
                return {
                 values: options ,
             };
         },    
      },
      { title: "Sales Person", field: "SalesPerson", editor: "input"},
      { title: "ReferenceNo", field: "ReferenceNo", editor: "input"},
      { title: "Receipt", field: "Receipt", editor: "input"},
      { title: "Status", field: "Status"},
      ],
     });
     table.on('cellEdited', (cell) => {
              var row = cell.getRow();
              var field = cell.getField();
              var value = cell.getValue();
                  var data = {
                    id: row.getData().ID, // Get the MID value from the row data
                    column: field,
                    value: value
                  };
                  console.log(data);
                // Update the data in the table
                axios.get(`/payment/edit/${data.id}`, {
                      params: {
                          column: data.column,
                          value: data.value
                      }
                  })
                .then(function(response) {
                  if (response.data.success) {
                    table.setData('/payment/view');
                  } else {
                      //alert("The provided data is already exists for another member");
                      table.setData('/payment/view');
                  }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(response.data.message);
                });
               })
        // Add row to bottom of table on button click
        document.getElementById("reactivity-add").addEventListener("click", function() {
          var newData = { ID: "" };
          tabledata.unshift(newData);
          table.setData(tabledata);
          // Send AJAX request to store the new data
          axios.post('/payment/store', newData)
            .then(function(response) {
              //table.setData('/payment/view');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              // Handle error
              console.error(error);
            });
        });
      
      });
</script>
```

This is the foreach

```
 if (category === "Product Payment" || category === "1") {
            product.forEach(function(item) {
              options[item.Name] = item.Name; // Get Data  like item.Name , item.Price and parse data to other cell 
          });
```

Cell I want to parse data from foreach

```
 { title: "Net Pay (₱)", field: "NetPay", editor: "number" },
 { title: "Discount", field: "Discount", editor: "number" },
      { title: "Grand Total", field: "GrandTotal", editor: "number", bottomCalc:"sum", bottomCalcParams:{
       precision:2,}},
```